# Ninja Forms: "Unknown Field type "" not found."

Tags: plugin-ninja-forms

I cannot figure out why Ninja Forms is throwing this error. Documentation does not have anything available on this error.

If I am making a form, and the field key is *firstname*, this error will come up and say it's not found when I go to publish it, and it corrupts my form.

> Unknown Field type "" not found.

Any advice would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use [Ninja Forms support](https://ninjaforms.com/contact/).  They recently made a large update and are continuously making improvements.